# JSF 1.2: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I have a DataTable with a `<h:column>` as `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`. Both the facet header and the DataTable rows content for that `<h:column>` are `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`. Below is the code I used:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable
        value="#{employeeService.employeeList }"
        var="empl"
        binding="#{employeeService.dataTablebinding }">
        ......
        ......
        ......
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">             
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkBoxAll" value="#{empl.checked }" valueChangeListener="#{employeeService.checkAll }" onclick="submit()"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="tableChkBox" value="#{empl.checked }" valueChangeListener="#{employeeService.getCheckChanged }" onclick="submit()"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

When I click the facet header checkbox, I want all the rows checkbox to be checked and the same for unchecked also. This is the code I have for the `ValueChangeListener` of that facet header checkbox:

```
public void checkAll(ValueChangeEvent event){       
    for(Employee empl : employeeList){
        employeeList.remove(empl);
        empl.setChecked(true);
        employeeList.add(empl);
    }               
}
```

I am getting the below excception:

```
SEVERE: AbortProcessingException thrown when processing event of type 'javax.faces.component.WrapperEvent' during phase 'PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3' for component with ID or Client ID of 'j_id7'
        27 Apr, 2013 8:20:38 PM javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot broadcastEvents
        SEVERE: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionValueChangeListener.processValueChange(MethodExpressionValueChangeListener.java:93)
            at javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent.processListener(ValueChangeEvent.java:134)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:771)
            at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:943)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:444)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:701)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
            at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
            at com.infy.service.DataTableService.checkAll(DataTableService.java:66)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
            at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
            at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionValueChangeListener.processValueChange(MethodExpressionValueChangeListener.java:91)
            ... 33 more
```

Please let me know the reason for this `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Turn the `foreach` loop into a `while` loop and use the iterators's `remove()` method to remove the elements of `employeeList`.

Comment: @Lion you too think that removing the element, modifying it and putting it back in **the same List** is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Ah! yes I didn't notice that, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(Employee empl : employeeList){
    empl.setChecked(true);
    }
```

As Luigi stated, you don't need to remove the employee from the list.

Comment: Please improve the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Ok this resolves the exception but in the UI, all the ckeckbox present in each row of the DataTable are not getting checked once I check the DataTable header. How to make that happen?

Comment: @user182944 you have two options: use an ajax action to re-render/update the UI after checking/unchecking the `<h:selectOneCheckbox>` or do it in plain javascript.

Comment: I dont want to use any javascript. I am using JSF 1.2, need further inputs on that ajax action.

Comment: @user182944 *I dont want to use any javascript* AJAX is by default JavaScript... Anyway, what have you done to invoke this action as ajax? Note that you are already using IceFaces. Or do you want to edit your question and ask for an IceFaces Ajax 101 class?

Comment: @user182944 nothing in plain JSF 1.x is ajaxified. If you want ajax in JSF 1.x, you should use third party libraries as IceFaces or RichFaces. Or move to JSF 2 where you have `<f:ajax>` and other frameworks that enhance the view layer like PrimeFaces, RichFaces (again) and/or IceFaces.

Comment: ok then if i use the same piece of code with icefaces then will it work? i.e. replacing the `<h:..>` tags with `<ice:..>` tags?

Comment: @user182944 you first have to **try something**, go **read on internet**, search **samples about this** and, basically, **learn**. If you have a specific problem, come back with that question and we will try to solve it. We're not here to give an IceFaces *how-to-use* lesson.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri tats the spirit...everyone should always keep on trying till the end :) Never give up!!!

Answer (score 3):

It is because while looping over the list you are modifying it:

```
for(Employee empl : employeeList){
    employeeList.remove(empl);
    empl.setChecked(true);
    employeeList.add(empl);
}
```

You need to use [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
for(Employee empl : employeeList){
   // employeeList.remove(empl); //Not required
    empl.setChecked(true);
    //employeeList.add(empl); //Not required
}
```

**Update** As mentioned by Luiggi Mendoza, you don't need to remove and add the element back to the list to alter it. Just take the reference and modify it.

Comment: You don't even need to remove and re-add the object from the list.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Correct, but the `ConcurrentModificationException` is due to list being modified while being iterator, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, you're right there. Still, the proposed solution isn't. By the way, the error isn't even related with JSF, is basic Java programming.

Comment: Ok this resolves the exception but in the UI, all the ckeckbox present in each row of the DataTable are not getting checked once I check the DataTable header. How to make that happen?

Comment: @user182944 You can write a java script function for that. Please create a new question for that. Thanks

Comment: @Apurv Nothing like creating a new question...its a part of this question only.

Comment: @user182944 When did this (check-box selection) become part of this question ? You can keep on asking questions through comments. Either ask all your questions in question at a time or ask each question independently.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem about jsf 1.2. The problem here is that you can't modify a Collection while you are iterating over it.

I think you get the same behaviour doing this:

```
public void checkAll(ValueChangeEvent event){       
for(Employee empl : employeeList){
    empl.setChecked(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes my mistake, hence they suggested me to use Iterator to resolve this issue